# control.focus() after selectedIndexChanged

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net

I need to focus on a textbox after an item has been selected from a dropdownlist.

I've tried control.focus() and setfocus().

The last thing I've tried was Set_Focus(dtbEffectiveDate.ClientID) inside the SelectedIndexChanged method with the folowing method.

```
Protected Sub Set_Focus(ByVal ControlName As String)
    Dim strScript As String

    strScript = "<script language=javascript> window.setTimeout(""" + ControlName + ".focus();"",0); </script>"
    RegisterStartupScript("focus", strScript)
End Sub
```

I'm out of answers so any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select the control in javascript with [document.getElementById(*id*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementByID):

```
 document.getElementById('"+ControlName+"').focus();
```

something like:

```
Protected Sub Set_Focus(ByVal ControlName As String)
    Dim strScript As String

    strScript = "<script language=javascript> window.setTimeout(document.getElementById('" + ControlName + "').focus();"",0); </script>"
    RegisterStartupScript("focus", strScript)
End Sub
```

Edit: I'm not entirely sure of the correct VB-syntax for escaping the quotes around ControlName.

Comment: Also, you will want to do it on `window.onload` to make sure the control exists before focusing.

Comment: "Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus."

Comment: @kyle: Can you post some code samples?  The code we are all proposing should work, and we will need more detail from you to give a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementByID) in javascript before you can call `focus` on it.

Try something like:

```
elem = document.getElementById('theCorrectId');
elem.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a server-side [`Control.Focus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.focus.aspx) method that will render the appropriate JavaScript automatically to put the focus on that control.

**Edit**

Here is an example:

```
Protected Sub MyDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(...)
    MyTextBox.Focus()
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried Control.Focus and Nothing happens. I think nothing happens because the page isn't completely loaded or the control isn't entirely exposed for the focus to occur

Comment: @kyle: Server-side, not javascript.  I updated post with an example.  It's hard to tell what's going on without a sample of your code.

Comment: I've tried control.focus() and setfocus(). <--Both of these I used as server side methods.

Comment: @kyle: Something is invisible or not rendered on the page then.  Changing your code to JavaScript is not going to make any difference if there is nothing to focus to (in fact `Control.Focus` is generally more accurate than rolling your own JavaScript).  We will probably need to see a concrete code example to offer more help.

Comment: I went through the code (2000 lines of server side code) and didn't find anything relevent to why that textbox is having problems.

Comment: @kyle: So what do you expect us to do??  Make a gut-feel wild educated guess as to what the problem is in your 2000 lines of server-side code?  You need to track down the problem, you have three perfectly-good solutions already for focusing a control.  You can create a simple "Test" page and validate that any of these methods do indeed work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Everything just magically started working.

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub ddlformtype_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    Set_Focus(dtbEffectiveDate.ClientID)
End Sub

Protected Sub Set_Focus(ByVal ControlName As String)
    Dim strScript As String

    strScript = "<script language=javascript> var x = document.getElementById('" + ControlName + "');  window.setTimeout(""x.focus()"",0); </script>"
    RegisterStartupScript("focus", strScript)
End Sub
```